# Why Computer Modern (latex) font doesn't contain all the math symbols?

Tags: fonts, latex

I downloaded the Computer Modern font, which is the default LaTeX font, to use it on my website, but when I opened the file with FontForge I noticed that it misses a lot of math symbols. It contains just the basic math symbols, such as + - : = < > and few others.

I download the font files from many sources but they seems to be all the same.

For example, the sign "not equal" `≠` is missing and if I write it, what is displayed is the default font symbol instead (Times New Roman I think). I tried typing `≠`, `&#x2260;`, `&#8800;`, `&ne;` but the result is always the same.

Dozens of other symbols are missing, is there a reason for this? Also, is there a way to add them to the font?

If you would like to inspect the file you can download it [here](https://www.checkmyworking.com/cm-web-fonts/Computer%20Modern%20Serif.zip), then open the file `cmunrm.woff` which corresponds to the normal style.

Here you can see a comparison of my site output and the latex output. As you can see all the letters and the 3 are displayed correctly (same font), while the "not equal" symbol is not (different fonts).

[image]

Comment: If you look into `fontmath.ltx` you can see that `\neq` is defined as `\DeclareRobustCommand\neq{\not=}`, so it is simply a combination of multiple symbols

Comment: I was also thinking that it is a combination of symbols, but so what about all the other ones which are not combination of other symbols?

Comment: Can you give an example of a missing symbol that is not a combination?

Comment: I don't know, maybe the `\in` set membership. Anyway, are you saying that the only way to add the missing symbols to the font is to manually add them? That is, create an svg file for each symbol and then add them to the font using FontForge ?

Comment: the computer modern symbol font from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm/ps-type1/bakoma/otf/ contains `\in`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Obsa0.png

Comment: Thanks! Is there an easy way to locate other symbols?

Comment: All the math symbols are in one file in the folder `opentype` at https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/lm-math